# How to update a source in a JavaScript Callback of Bokeh in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh, bokehjs

I am adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38486119) for my case, where I want an interactive, standalone graph where the slider selects which column of the data to plot in a bar chart. (Standalone is crucial, I cannot run a Bokeh server, thus the need for [JavaScript callbacks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html).)

The data is a rectangle of floats with 100 rows in each of the 38 columns, which all have string labels like `'40'` etc. (This is how pandas `.read_csv()` handles numerics in the header by default.) Here is a sample from the top left corner (3x3, plus the row and column labels):

```
        # ,        40,        41,        42,
   1.00000,   1.00000,   0.99287,   0.98489,
   2.00000,   1.00000,   0.99348,   0.98626,
   3.00000,   1.00000,   0.99433,   0.98922,
```

The code below produces the graph for the first column but does not update the graph upon moving the slider.

By poking at it, I suspect the issue is with the JavaScript code, though [ColumnDataSource](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/models/sources.html#ColumnDataSource) remains a bit mysterious to me. (A more straightforward dictionary of numeric column labels to lists of the numbers in the column does not work as `datasource_available`, though corresponds to the linked answer's use case.)

```
datadf = pd.read_csv('male_survival_by_pctile.csv')
datadf.set_index('# ',inplace=True)
years = range(40,77)
data = {}
data_available = {}

for year in years:
    data[year] = {'top':datadf[str(year)],'x':range(1,101)}
data_available = ColumnDataSource.from_df(datadf)

from bokeh.core.properties import field
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, SingleIntervalTicker,
                          Slider, Button, Label, CustomJS)
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

source_visible = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=range(1,101),top=data_available[str(years[0])]))
source_available = ColumnDataSource(data=data_available)

plot = figure(output_backend="webgl")
plot.xaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=.01)
plot.xaxis.axis_label = "Income percentile"
plot.yaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=.05)
plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Survival rate"

label = Label(x=1.1, y=18, text=str(years[0]), text_font_size='70pt', text_color='#eeeeee')
plot.add_layout(label)

plot.vbar(top='top',x='x',width=1,source=source_visible)

slider = Slider(start=years[0], end=years[-1], value=years[0], step=1, title="Age")

slider.callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source_visible=source_visible,
              source_available=source_available), code="""
        var selected_function = cb_obj.get('value').toString();
        // Get the data from the data sources
        var data_visible = source_visible.get('data');
        var data_available = source_available.get('data');
        // Change bar height to the selected value
        data_visible.top = data_available[selected_function];
        // Update the plot
        source_visible.trigger('change');
    """)

layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the `CustomJS` code as you suspected. There are two things that need to be fixed.

1. Bokeh has deprecated `get()` and `set()` methods and replaced them by `getv()` or `setv()`. However, the preferred way of accessing or modifying model properties is through usual JavaScript attributes, e.g., `source_visible.data`.
2. Bokeh has [deprecated](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bokeh/bokeh/master/sphinx/source/docs/releases/0.12.6.rst) `trigger('change')` and replaced it by `change.emit()`.

The fixed `CustomJS` code:

```
slider.callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source_visible=source_visible,
              source_available=source_available), code="""
        var selected_function = cb_obj.value.toString();
        // Get the data from the data sources
        var data_visible = source_visible.data;
        var data_available = source_available.data;
        // Change bar height to the selected value
        data_visible.top = data_available[selected_function];
        // Update the plot
        source_visible.change.emit();
    """)
```

JavaScript errors and warnings are seen in the browser's console. [Here are instructions for opening the console in different browsers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).